# Como registrar classes de serviço do Datasnap em runtime no Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

No **Delphi XE3** eu conseguia registrar minhas classes de serviço fazendo o seguinte:

```object-pascal
type
  TRegisterServices = class
    class procedure RegisterServices(AOwner: TComponent; DSServer: TDSServer);
  private
    class procedure RegisterService(AOwner: TComponent; DSServer: TDSServer;
      AClass: TCustomServiceClass; ALifeCycle: string = TDSLifeCycle.Invocation);
  end;

implementation

class procedure TRegisterServices.RegisterServices(AOwner: TComponent; DSServer: TDSServer);
begin
  RegisterService(AOwner, DSServer, TUsuarioService);
end;

class procedure TRegisterServices.RegisterService(AOwner: TComponent;
  DSServer: TDSServer; AClass: TCustomServiceClass; ALifeCycle: string);
begin
  Assert(AOwner <> nil, 'Serviço ainda não criado');
  Assert(not DSServer.Started, 'Não é possível adicionar classes com o servidor ativo');

  TSimpleServerClass.Create(AOwner, DSServer, AClass, ALifeCycle);
end;
```

Por meio dessa classe eu registrava todos as minhas classes de serviço.

A **TSimpleServerClass** era:

```object-pascal
type
  TSimpleServerClass = class(TDSServerClass)
  private
    FPersistentClass: TPersistentClass;
  protected
    function GetDSClass: TDSClass; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AServer: TDSCustomServer; 
      AClass: TPersistentClass; ALifeCycle: string = TDSLifeCycle.Invocation); 
      reintroduce; overload;
  end;

constructor TSimpleServerClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AServer: TDSCustomServer;  
  AClass: TPersistentClass; ALifeCycle: String);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FPersistentClass := AClass;
  self.Server := AServer;
  self.LifeCycle := ALifeCycle;
end;

function TSimpleServerClass.GetDSClass: TDSClass;
var 
  IsAdapted: Boolean; 
begin 
  result := nil; 
  if FPersistentClass <> nil then 
  begin 
    IsAdapted := FPersistentClass.InheritsFrom(TProviderDataModule); 
    result := TDSClass.Create(FPersistentClass, IsAdapted); 
    if IsAdapted then 
      result := TDSClass.Create(TDSProviderDataModuleAdapter, result); 
  end; 
end;
```

Esse exemplo não funciona mais no **Delphi XE7**:

```object-pascal
function TSimpleServerClass.GetDSClass: TDSClass;
var 
  IsAdapted: Boolean; 
begin 
  result := nil; 
  if FPersistentClass <> nil then 
  begin 
    IsAdapted := FPersistentClass.InheritsFrom(TProviderDataModule); 
    result := TDSClass.Create(FPersistentClass, IsAdapted); 
    if IsAdapted then 
      result := TDSClass.Create(TDSProviderDataModuleAdapter, result); 
  end; 
end;
```

Então adaptei para o seguinte, de acordo com o método interno (era o mesmo processo nas versões anteriores - **Delphi XE3**, por exemplo):

```object-pascal
function TSimpleServerClass.GetDSClass: TDSClass;
var 
  IsAdapted: Boolean; 
  LAdapter: TServerClassAdapter;
begin 
  LAdapter := TServerClassAdapterFactory.GetAdapter(sProviderServerAdapter);
  try
    IsAdapted := (LAdapter <> nil) and LAdapter.IsSupportedType(PersistentClass);
    Result := TDSClass.Create(PersistentClass, IsAdapted);
    if IsAdapted then
      result := TDSClass.Create(LAdapter.GetType, Result);
  finally
    LAdapter.Free;
  end;  
end;
```

E todas as minhas classes de serviço herdavam de:

```object-pascal
{$MethodInfo on}
TCustomService = class(TInterfacedPersistent)
private
  FDbConnection: TDbConnection;
  FResponsibleOfConnection: boolean;
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce; overload;
  constructor Create(ADbConnection: TDbConnection); overload;
  destructor Destroy; override;
public
  property DbConnection: TDbConnection read FDbConnection;
end;
{$MethodInfo off}
```

Meus métodos ***create*** e ***destructor***, existentes nessa base padrão eram executados.

Agora com o **Delphi XE7** não estou conseguindo fazer com que o método **Create** seja executado em minhas classes de serviço herdadas desssa classe base.

Como exemplo:

```object-pascal
TUsuarioService = class(TCustomService, IUsuario)
  function TryLogin(ALogin: string; ASenha: string; var AToken: string): boolean;
  function Get(ALogin: string): TUsuario;
  function List: TObjectList<TUsuario>;
  function AddOrUpdate(var AUsuario: TUsuario): boolean;
  function Remove(ALogin: string): boolean;
end;
```

Como resolver tal problema?

Comment: Resolvi esse problema declarando a unit "Datasnap.DSProviderDataModuleAdapter"

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu problema, momentaneamente, fazendo com que minha classe `TCustomService` herde de `TDSServerModule` e então faço uso dos eventos `OnCreate` e `OnDestroy`.

Não é uma solução para o problema apresentado mas é o que está me ajudando no momento.

Ainda gostaria de uma resposta para o problema apresentado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.. Resolvi o problema reescrevendo o método GetDSClass.
Percebi que faltou algumas linhas no seu método.

```
function GetDSClass: TDSClass;
var

  IsAdapted: Boolean;

  LAdapter: TServerClassAdapter;

begin

  LAdapter := TServerClassAdapterFactory.GetAdapter(sProviderServerAdapter);

  try

    IsAdapted := (LAdapter <> Nil) and LAdapter.IsSupportedType(FpersistentClass);

    Result := TDSClass.Create(FPersistentClass, IsAdapted);

    if IsAdapted then

      Result := TDSClass.Create(LAdapter.Getype, Result)

    Finally

      LAdapter.Free;

    end;

  end;
```